# setting paginationInitialPage for pagination "remote" has no effect

Tags: ajax, typescript, tabulator

Tabulator Version: 4.7

Hi Tabulator community. I have a tabulator table with paging "remote" and am experiencing the issue, that tabulator always initially loads data with page = 1 even when I set **paginationInitialPage** in the Tabulator constructor.

```
this.tabulator = new Tabulator("#myDivContainer", {
    pagination:"remote",
    ajaxURL:"https://myserver/getdata", 
    paginationSize:10,
    paginationInitialPage:2,
    ... (columns definitions, layout etc.)
});
```

By logging the request sent to the backend I found out, that Tabulator ignores the paginationInitialPage property and initially always requests page 1.

Logged request: `GET https://myserver/getdata?searchValue=abc&size=10&page=1`

First I maybe need to explain, how the "searchValue=abc" gets added to the request. I utilize the tabulator table with a filter form. Data loading gets triggered on form submit by calling the following method (simplified):
`this.tabulator.setData("https://myserver/getdata?searchValue=abc");`

I found out that this method call actually appends the current paging information "&size=X&page=Y" to the request and I tried to intercept it by implementing / overwriting the following **ajaxURLGenerator** method. By debugging this in the frontend I got the following result on initial load:
[current paging info in params != tabulator paginationInitialPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czvrc.png)

This leads to a wrong paging. Yes, I can change the request in this ajaxURLGenerator method to return the correct data set but the tabulator-"brain" always thinks that it's page 1 and therefore this leads to pagination buttons not working correctly (data from page 2, tabulator thinks it's page 1). My fix to this is doing a manual `this.tabulator.setPage(2)` after the initial load which leads to another async request being sent. Workaround is OK but if possible I'd really like to avoid multiple requests for one page load...

The only thing I found remotely close to my case is the following issue, I don't get the console error *'Pagination Error - Requested page is out of range of 1 - 1: 2'* however and my request reaches the backend as well:
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3101

I really would be thankful if someone can tell me if the above issue fix also fixes my problem so I would consider upgrading to Tabulator v5.0.

Thanks & kind regards